# Does a phased-out Ring-bearer stop being the Ring-bearer when the Ring tempts you?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When the Ring tempts you, a creature you control becomes the Ring-bearer and the previous Ring-bearer, if any, stops being it.

> 701.52a Certain spells and abilities have the text “the Ring tempts you.” Each time the Ring tempts you, choose a creature you control. That creature becomes your Ring-bearer until another creature becomes your Ring-bearer or another player gains control of it.

A designation, while not explicitely defined in the rules, is a marker inherent to an object or player. For example, see the definition of "Monstrous".

> 701.31b Monstrous is a designation that has no rules meaning other than to act as a marker that the monstrosity action and other spells and abilities can identify.

The event of phasing itself does not remove the designation via 701.52a since it remains the same object and no change of control happens. The phasing rule 702.26d does not mention what happens to designations on phasing, but that can only mean that phasing does not affect them.

> 702.26d The phasing event doesn’t actually cause a permanent to change zones or control [..] Counters and stickers remain on a permanent while it’s phased out. [..]

For a rule to affect phased out permanents, the rule has to mention phased out permanents explicitely.

> 702.26b If a permanent phases out, its status changes to “phased out.” **Except for rules and effects that specifically mention phased-out permanents, a phased-out permanent is treated as though it does not exist.** It can’t affect or be affected by anything else in the game. A permanent that phases out is removed from combat. (See rule 506.4.)

The Ring-bearer rules don't mention phasing, so 701.52a is unable to remove the designation while the Ring-bearer is phased out.

So the question is: **Can a phased out permanent stop being the Ring-bearer, and what is the rules justification for it?**

Comment: This is amusing because canonically the Ring-bearer *does* "phase out" (become invisible) and cannot be interacted with by other permanents (say, orcs) if they wear the One Ring.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, a phased out permanent can stop being the Ring-bearer.**

Rule 701.52a says (with my emphasis):

> Certain spells and abilities have the text “the Ring tempts you.” Each time the Ring tempts you, choose a creature you control. **That creature becomes your Ring-bearer *until another creature becomes your Ring-bearer* or another player gains control of it.**

Then [rule 702.26f](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Phasing) says (with my emphasis):

> **Continuous effects that affect a phased-out permanent may expire while that permanent is phased out. If so, they will no longer affect that permanent once it’s phased in.** In particular, effects with “for as long as” durations that track that permanent (see rule 611.2b) end when that permanent phases out because they can no longer see it.

Technically, the part of the rule that makes a creature a Ring-bearer is not a continuous effect as defined in [rule 611.1](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Continuous_effect):

> A continuous effect modifies characteristics of objects, modifies control of objects, or affects players or the rules of the game, for a fixed or indefinite period.

However, rule 702.26f establishes that something with a duration that affects a permanent can expire while the permanent is phased out, and that thing then does not affect that permanent after it phases in. There is no contradiction with rule 702.26b here, because the Ring-bearer rule is not directly acting on the phased-out permanent. Instead, it is only ceasing an existing action that was originally taken on a phased-in permanent.

Comment: Well that is the crux of the matter. Designations such as Ring-bearer are not continuous effects and carry no inherent effect. The only continuous effects in this context come from the Ring emblem, but the designation itself doesn't. So how does 702.26f apply to the designation?

Comment: Also, remember the advice we gave in the previous QA: If it's not in the rules, it doesn't happen. 702.26f refers to continuous effects only, so if it's not a CE, it's not affected.

Comment: You can apply that both ways. There's nothing in the phasing rules that say that designations phase out along with the permanent they refer to, which means that the phasing rules cannot prevent another rule from manipulating those designations.

Comment: Well, since a phased out Ring-bearer does not exist as far as the Ring rules are concerned, it seems safe to assume its designation can't be removed either. You don't seem to dispute that assumption in your answer either, instead focusing on the time immediately *after* phase in. If you can make the case that the Ring rules see the phased out bearer and remove the designation, or that the designation somehow doesn't phase out together with the permanent it's on, let's hear it

Comment: Consider the designation as an arrow pointing to a permanent. Phasing out the creature doesn't do anything immediately, but if you move the arrow to point to something else, it's still pointing to that something else after the creature phases in. I'm not saying that the Ring rules can see the phased out Ring-bearer, I'm saying that they don't need to.

Comment: @Hackworth: My reading (and I am a MTG noob, admittedly) would be the Ring-bearer phases out, the Ring-bearer "does not exist", and so the Ring rules force the owner to choose of a Ring-bearer (which cannot be the old Ring-bearer as it does not exist), which moves the Ring-bearer designator to the new creature. I read it as you always choose a "new" Ring-bearer, just you can choose the same Ring-bearer repeatedly (if existent).

Comment: I think nobody is disputing that if the ring tempts you while your most recent Ring-bearer phases out, you have to choose a new Ring-bearer from among your other phased-in creatures. The question here is whether the previous Ring-bearer also continues to be your Ring-bearer after it phases in (resulting in simultaneously having two Ring-bearers).

Comment: Nothing says that any given designation has to be unique, see monstrous. Designation uniqueness, where intended, is ensured through proper rules design. I don't think you can substantiate that unique pointer analogy through rules, since designations are not properly defined. Ring-bearer is obviously intended to be unique, but I think they just forgot to account for phasing.

Comment: The point of the arrow analogy was not specifically that the designation is unique, but that it doesn't phase out. I could instead say that choosing a new Ring-bearer creates a new arrow, and you remove all other arrows whenever you create a new arrow. Either way, the point is that the thing the rule is operating on is the arrow(s), not the creature, so it is not impacted by phasing.

Comment: So the pointer analogy seems to be a rewording of the claim that there is a 702.26f analogue that would apply to designations. I still don't think that analogue exists, and we are back to my first 2 comments.

Comment: As I said before, the strict reading of the rules goes both ways. Point to a rule that says that designations *do* phase out with the permanent they refer to, and I'll delete this answer.

Comment: My perspective here is that there is a general principle that time marches on and effects start and end independent of the existence or status of individual objects that they might effect or refer to, and that the first sentence of 702.26f is simply a reminder rule of how this principle should be considered in the context of phasing. Therefore, its conclusions should not be considered to be restricted to continuous effects, even though it only refers to them.

Comment: "Point to a rule that says that designations do phase out with the permanent they refer to [..]" Designations are not defined, so there is no rule to quote. However, the known examples agree that permanents can "have" designations or "are" what the designation represents. When you designate a permanent and it phases out, you no longer control a permanent with that designation. I find that sufficient proof that the designation and the information it represents has phased out too, i.e. it no longer exists. That does not imply I want your answer retracted, that is entirely up to you.

Comment: That being said, I find your 702.26f analogy more persuasive philosophically, but still not sufficient for the game rules - the rule says and does exactly what it says, no more and no less. Unlike the designation definition or lack thereof, there is nothing to piece together or interpret with varying wordings. If the rules managers want the Ring-bearer designation to expire like a continuous effect, which I even agree they want, I say they have to write a rule to that effect because designations, as we agree, are not CEs.

Comment: The rule says that the designation lasts until another creature becomes your ring bearer. In this scenario, another creature becomes your ring bearer, so the designation no longer applies. That's what the rule *says*, no more, no less. The way I see it, it really is that simple.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to answer this question is to test on Arena (and to then assume that Arena has implemented the rules correctly.)  I ran this test last night.

If you phase out your ring bearer (e.g. [Teferi's Protection](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Teferi%27s%20Protection)), and do nothing else, when your ring bearer phases in, it is still the ring bearer.

If you phase out your ring bearer, and the ring tempts you again, and you assign a new creature as your ring bearer, then when the former ring bearer phases in, they are no longer the ring bearer.

Comment: "then assume that Arena has implemented the rules correctly" This is a moderately large assumption.